# Sum up numbers in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
myfile = open("file.txt")
lines = myfile.readlines
myfile.close
```

I am stuck here, having problems sum up numbers in file.
They are

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
42
9001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a step by step process in order to achieve what you're asking for.

```
file = open("numbers.txt", "r") #read the file
file = file.read().splitlines() #create a list where each value is a line of the file
file = list(map(int, file)) #convert each of the values on the list to "int"
print(sum(file)) #sum all the values inside the list
```

1. You need to read the file
2. Create a list where each of the values is a line of the text
3. Convert all the values of the list to "int" as they're "inserted" as
   "str"
4. Sum all the values inside the list

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each line to an integer and then use the `sum` function to obtain the sum:

```
print(sum(map(int, open("file.txt"))))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to not use map becasue I don't get what it is.

Comment: @zetongli `print(sum(int(x) for x in open("file.txt")))`

Comment: Sorry, I am new. Could you show me step by step? Thanks